# How to configure fail2ban with systemd journal?

Tags: fail2ban, systemd-journald

I've install `fail2ban` on Debian Jessie LXC container, currently it's failing due to:

```
Starting authentication failure monitor: fail2ban
ERROR  No file(s) found for glob /var/log/auth.log
ERROR  Failed during configuration: Have not found any log file for ssh jail
```

There's no `syslog` or `rsyslog` on the system and thus `/var/log/auth.log` is not generated. Is there a way how to tell `fail2ban` to use output of `journalctl _COMM=sshd`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**For systemd systems:**

You have to specify the backend in `/etc/fail2ban/jail.conf` to use `systemd` as follows:

```
[DEFAULT]
backend = systemd
```

Then restart fail2ban:

```
systemctl restart fail2ban
```

---

**Edit:**

I'm a heavy CentOS/RHEL/Fedora guy so you may have to adapt what I say a bit. As far as this answer, you may have to update the fail2ban package to a version that supports systemd as a backend or you'll have to install `rsyslog` and add the following to your `/etc/rsyslog.conf`:

```
authpriv.*      /var/log/auth.log
```

This will make sure sshd auth logs are logging to `/var/log/auth.log` which will be read by the default `pyinotify` backend in fail2ban:

Comment: `systemd` option doesn't seem to be supported by `fail2ban 0.8.13`: `fail2banERROR  NOK: ("Unknown backend systemd. Must be among ['pyinotify', 'gamin', 'polling'] or 'auto'",)`

Comment: @Tombart What version of Debian are you running? Looks like you need an updated fail2ban package that supports the systemd backend OR you can install rsyslog and add the right configuration to your rsyslog.conf

Comment: It's the latest version of Debian 8 Jessie which comes with `systemd` support.

Comment: @MatthewSanabria, why `have to install rsyslog` in centos?

Comment: How do you specify/configure the systemd unit? How does fail2ban know where to look?

Answer (score 8):

There is an Issue with the config files.

I had jail.conf and `jail.d/defaults-debian.conf`

The content of the latter one was:

```
[sshd]
enabled = true
```

Because of backend not being set here the default value is used instead of the one in `jail.conf`. The Problem ist described in detail here: https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/issues/1372

adding `backend = systemd` did the trick.

defaults-debian.conf

```
[sshd]
enabled = true
backend = systemd
```

Comment: To be more explicit about this, the admin can create any file named like `/etc/fail2ban/jail.d/*.local` and include the desired configurations starting with `[sshd]`. This allows for customizing without touching the files that come with the package by default.

Comment: Finally an answer! Thank you. The configs are abstracted up the wazoo with `%()` placeholders and whatnot. Additionally there's files like `paths-arch.conf` `paths-opensuse.conf` in the default config. WHY IN THE WORLD would you even include those in a debian distributed package?!

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem. Rather than figuring it out, I ended up re-installing syslogd to generate the logfile(s).

`apt-get install inetutils-syslogd`

It may take a few mins after installation for the log file to be created - It will be created when a log entry is added.

I wouldn't recommend it long term (as it doesn't actually fix the problem), but if you want fail2ban working immediately, it does the job.

Comment: Removing the squeaky door because you can't find the oil can is no solution!

Comment: As mentioned, I didn't recommend it long term. This was one of the things that didn't work out of the box (for me) when systemd was first a thing. Ultimately, the REAL fix was for the package maintainers to fix the default install. Remember, this answer is now nearly 8 years old.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need fail2ban version 0.9.0 which can support systemd, while Debian Jessie has 0.8.3 in the repository.

Try downloading and installing from sources, or look for the alternative repos.

Regards.